# GNU linker LENGTH section multiplication factor

Tags: linker, gnu, ld, linker-scripts

The length section of the memory command in a linker file takes K, M symbols to indicate kilobytes, megabytes etc. Is the multiplier 1000 or 1024?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this is months later but I was wondering about the K and M parts myself.

The LD manual states that the expression "must be numerical only and evaluate to a constant". It then blithely proceeds to use an example of 256K and 4M which is slightly disconcerting!

The relevant source code files (in binutils/ld) appear to be ldlex.l and ldgram.y. In the lexer, an expression can end with `[M|K|m|k]`.

For M or m, the value is multiplied by 1024 * 1024. 
For K or k, the value is multiplied by 1024.

Edit: I had read sections of the LD manual in isolation, which can be misleading! When I read more of the linker manual, I can see that it does specify what it means by numerical constant, which does include suffixes like K and M:
https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Constants.html#Constants

Comment: Thank you! I navigated to the source per your answer and it is correct: https://sourceware.org/git/?p=binutils-gdb.git;a=blob_plain;f=ld/ldlex.l;hb=HEAD

Comment: I should have included the link rather than make you do the work there! Funny thing though - I answered this question because I hadn't read all of the manual, wondered the same thing about K and M and hit your question with google!! But when I read more of the manual, it did clarify what it meant by constant. I added an edit to my answer :-)

Comment: Only one thing to say in response to this answer... THANK YOU!